# How to send the RC522 RFID reader into sleep mode?

Tags: arduino, low-power, rfid, sleep

I'm trying to get the power consumption of a MFRC522 RFID module down, currently while running it consumes about 4mA. There should be a way to put it into sleep mode, I just can't find any documentation on it. I'm using the module with a arduino currently if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've found it already, but from Table3 of MRFC522 datasheet it says Hold the reset pin low for low power mode.